# JS request without showing API key for leaflet

Tags: javascript, php, django, proxy

I would like to request a Leaflet tilelayer without exposing my API key and secret.

I believe I can solve this by using my own server as a proxy but I get a 500 error in the JS console when trying the below: (I've the feeling the error comes from how return the response back to the client, in python the response gives a 200 and if I try to print the content I can see all the data)

views.py:

```
# echo function
def echo(request):

    response = requests.get("https://api.maptiler.com/maps/[..........]")
    return response
```

And the JS part for reference:

```
  style: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/echo'
```

Comment: SO is not a code conversion service.  There's nothing that advanced happening in there.  You should be able to make your own attempt.

Comment: sorry for that. had tried some code in django that didn't work, so taught it might be more clear if I would post an example of what I wanted to achieve

Comment: Of course it is important to know what you want to achieve.  But it is equally important to see what you've tried, along with the result, so we can help figure out where you've gone wrong.  If you're getting a 500 status response, then you probably have entries in your server error logs that you can check for more details. The example that you showed in PHP was using querystring params to populate the remote request. You're not showing that in the Python above. Is that still happening? If so, it would be good to see that. I'd also try hardcoding those values as a test and see what happens

Comment: Thanks Patrick, for loading the style no querystring params are needed I believe. In python I’ve printed the response status (200) and content without problems